# Downloadable archives of illumination in Europe?

Tags: data-request, weather, europe

I'm trying to make a DLI ([Daily Light Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daily_light_integral)) map of Europe (what DLI has each country per month), but I can't find the data to do that.

Is there any Open Source dataset that includes the DLI information, or some data usable to calculate the DLI? *(Global Illumination, PAR (Photosynthetically Active Radiation), quantity of light, etc)*.